# CD для Gitlab Container Registry

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

Docker image хранится в Gitlab Container Registry. Как настроить загрузку образа на сервер, чтобы при пуше в ветку обновлялся сервер? Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону гуглить и какой выбрать хостинг с поддержкой докера

Comment: Делать `docker push` как завершающее действие в `.gitlab-ci.yml`.